# Groovy regex. Matching begining of the line

Tags: regex, groovy

I am little puzzled by Groovy regex behavior.

```
"dog" == /dog/ - return true

"dog" == /^dog/ - return false
```

My understanding that ^ matches start of the line so second expression should return true as well.

What I am actually trying to do is to replace "#" at beginning of the line using

```
line = line.replace(/^#/, '')
```

but "#" does not get removed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Groovy, there are many ways of declaring Strings ie;

```
println( 'foo' ) // regular string
println( '''foo''' ) // multiline string
println( "foo" ) // templatable string
println( """foo""" ) // multiline templatable string
println( /foo/ ) // slashy string
println( $/foo/$ ) // dollar slashy string (also multiline)
```

All of the above are Strings, so:

```
"dog" == /dog/ - return true
```

As both sides are a String (and the same String), so they equal each other

If you want to do Pattern matching, you need the `==~` operator:

```
"dog" ==~ /^dog/
```

Which returns true.  Not sure why you have a `)` in your `replaceAll`:

```
def line = '#Foo'
line.replaceAll( /^#/, '' ) == 'Foo'
```

Returns true

Comment: The ")" is a typo. I have removed it. So basically my original problem was that I was using "replace", instead of "replaceAll". "replace" does not take RegEx, so my string were not treated as RegEx. Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation on Strings